# iOS Popover blocking calling button

Tags: ios, xcode, popover, uistoryboardsegue

On Xcode 9.3 I'm using storyboards to create an iPad UI.On the tap of a UIButton a Popover segue is called showing up a TableViewController.
The TableView is called and it shows up and it's dismissed as expected.
However, no matter what Anchor checkbox I check on the Attributes Inspector of the Segue, the popover tableview shows right in front of the button calling the segue. I wanted it popping up from the right side but it seems to popup always from the left side of the UIButton.

Maybe I'm missing something and I'd appreciate any hints.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: we need to see the code where you implement this

Comment: Everything is implemented using storyboards... No code as of yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many research and Trial & Error, I found out how to do it...
It so appears that the Popover view has to have the CGRect of the item calling it. So there is no way to avoid code to do that.

There are to ways to do it, either calling the segue programmatically from the button or via the `prepareForSegue` function. I chose to do the later as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let popOver=segue.destination as? DataSelectionTableViewController, let temporaryButton=sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }



    popOver.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popOver.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = temporaryButton
    popOver.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = temporaryButton.bounds

    if segue.identifier=="popOverSegueID"{

        popOver.dataArray=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    }
}
```

I the above snippet the PopOver view is a TableViewController. On the main view there will only be this kind of segue showing up and the popover will be called from 3 different buttons populating the TableView with different data. If the Main View has different segues or popovers, the whole code should be located inside the

```
if segue.identifier=="popOverSegueID"{ ... }
```

I just did it like I showed to avoid copy-pasting code.

I hope it helps.